# What algorithm is mostly used to interpolate animations?

Tags: algorithm, animation, interpolation, standards

Because DCC tools supports very many options, we resample the animation curve splines, but I think it still need to be interpolated. I think there's some de facto standard for this animation interpolation. Or no interpolation. Can I know what's the mostly used interpolation method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most common form of interpolation is [linear interpolation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_interpolation).

However, in the case of animating curve splines, another common one is [spline interpolation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spline_interpolation).

Answer (score 2):

In general, you should have an interpolation function f of any kind that satisfies:
    f(0) = 0;
    f(1) = 1;
    f(x) is continuous for all 0 < x < 1 (this can obviously be relaxed if you want jumps);    0 <= f(x) <= 1; and 
    f(x) increasing for 0 < x < 1 (unless you want goofy effects).

Ones that are computationally easier to do are preferred. For example, one may use
    f(x) = 3x^2 - 2x^3
instead of 
    f(x) = sin(pi x).
Both of these have roughly the same shape over the unit interval.

Once you decide on your interpolation function, then simply compute A * f(x) + B * (1 - f(x)) to interpolate between the two values.